# Parallelize estimation of expectation values in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, optimization

## Edit

I tried using python multiprocessing library. The result with 8 cores isn't always faster than the original script that uses only one core. How can i improve the algorithm?

---

Suppose i've a matrix of $n \times n$ quantum circuits, and each circuit has $k$ parameters. I want to calculate the expectation value for a given operator $\hat{O}$ for all circuits. For example the following code (**old**):

```python
import numpy as np

from qiskit              import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.primitives   import Estimator


n = 10
estimator   = Estimator()
matrix_circ = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=QuantumCircuit)
# a random operator 
operator    =  SparsePauliOp(['II', 'XZ'],coeffs=[1.0, 0.5])

#define matrix of circuits. Each circuit has k parameters
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        matrix_circ[i,j] = # ... a circuit with k parameters

parameters = np.random.random(len(matrix[0,0].parameters))

matrix_values = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        job = estimator.run( matrix_circ[i,j] ,  operator , parameters)
        estimator_result   = job.result()
        values             = estimator_result.values
        matrix_values[i,j] = values[0]
```

**New code**:

```python
import numpy as np

from qiskit              import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.primitives   import Estimator

import multiprocessing as mp

n = 10
estimator   = Estimator()
matrix_circ = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=QuantumCircuit)
# a random operator 
operator    =  SparsePauliOp(['II', 'XZ'],coeffs=[1.0, 0.5])

#define matrix of circuits. Each circuit has k parameters
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        matrix_circ[i,j] = # ... a circuit with k parameters

parameters = np.random.random(len(matrix[0,0].parameters))

def exp_val(i , j , operator , estimator , parameters):
        job = estimator.run( matrix_circ[i,j] ,  operator , parameters)
        estimator_result   = job.result()
        values             = estimator_result.values
        result = values[0]
        return result

elements = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):   
        elements.append([i , j , operator , estimator , parameters])
processes = 8
pool = mp.Pool(processes=processes)
r = pool.starmap(exp_val, elements)

matrix_values = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        matrix_values[i,j] = r[j + i * n]
```

Since the parameters are fixed before the for-loop, it doesn't need to be sequential. Is it possible to parallelize the for-loop?